# Girl under a man's power meets an alien friend

Tags: story-identification

This was a library book I read maybe 5 or 6 years ago in the uk, I can’t remember the cover.
There is a girl protagonist who is a courtesan or bonded servant to this mega rich guy who has vast resources and power. In the story he is going around the galaxy sorting out business deals.

I only recall one main scene so I hope it triggers recognition. They land on a jungle planet for a bit of recreational hunting and him and his staff are hovering above the trees on gravity sleds with their weapons booming in the distance.
The girl gets bored and walks into the jungle nearby, as she gets further in she freezes as she notices movement right in front of her. This proves to be one of the hunters targets, a biped with like rhino skin, it is hiding from the guns.

The girl learns that she can talk to it through her universal translator and that the creatures are not classed as sentient despite high intelligence, it is hoped this status will change soon. She learns that this alien is female as well and soon they’re friends and enjoying a girly giggle.
A siren sounds for the end of the hunt, she tells the alien to hide for a while longer and she returns to the ship or base.

The next day her boss comes for her early and tells her to dress and come with him, he gives her a seriously cool black leather jacket and takes her on a tour of the facilities, then they enter a large room.

Chained up and sobbing is the female alien, she’s been skinned alive from neck to hips, the aliens eyes look at her in shock and horror and gasps “But we were friends!”
At that point the girl realises she is wearing her new friends hide as a jacket and that she must have been followed into the jungle by a surveillance drone.

The guy drags her out and makes her continue the tour with him, all the while she has to keep wearing the jacket

Comment: so this was one short scene in a novel? Can you recall if its was a recently published book or older? You read it in the UK would you be able to say of the author was british? All these things help narrow it down!

Comment: It took maybe a chapter of the book to describe that scene, I couldn't say if it was written by a Brit or American (I think maybe a woman author but I'm not sure) it seemed a new book so prob written between 2010 to 2015. The book was fairly thick but it's frustrating me trying to recall any further plot details - only that one scene stayed in my head

Comment: This is definetly not a book I have read but here is a list of SF novels published between 2010 and 2020. See if anything rings a bell. Beyond that I doubt i can help further as this is definetly not something I have read. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Category:2010s_science_fiction_novels